# Mysql sum query returning incorrect result when using multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

My query is returning incorrect sum of 2 columns from 2 sub tables, i searched over google and also looked the suggestion on stackoverflow but they never worked.

```
   si_invoices
   -----------------------------
   id, date
   1, 2014-05-07


   si_invoice_items
   -----------------------------
   id, invoice_id, date , total
   1, 100, 2014-05-07, 200
   2, 100, 2014-05-07, 200

   si_payment
   -----------------------------
   id, ac_inv_id, date , payment
   1, 100, 2014-05-07, 100
   2, 100, 2014-05-07, 200

   SELECT  SI.*,SUM(SII.total) as total,SUM(SIP.payment) as payment FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM si_invoices GROUP BY si_invoices.id) AS SI
     LEFT JOIN si_invoice_items SII ON SII.invoice_id = SI.id
     LEFT JOIN si_payment SIP ON SIP.ac_inv_id = SII.invoice_id
   GROUP BY SI.id
```

It should return 400 sum for field 'total' in sql but it return 800 and same as for 'payment'. Can you please point out what is the error in my query. Please help, appreciated.

Thanks
M.S

Comment: show the expected result you want

Comment: I already explained desired result. Please go through the question. It should return 400 as sum but it is actually returning 800.

Comment: 1.SELECT * FROM si_invoices GROUP BY si_invoices.id must be giving syntax error. Group By has only one column and you are trying to fetch more than one col.

Comment: SII.invoice_id = SI.id .It should be returning you null values. There is no matching data in their respective tables.So, final result must be Null. How are you getting any output (worng/right) with such syntax errors and null data mapping.

Comment: Instead of placing the expected result value.It would help if you mention the desired output you are trying to achieve.Is it just the sum of total and payment that you want to get for all the ids available in si_invoices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the totals directly because your joins are probably creating more rows in combination that you want.

Try the following:

```
SELECT id, MAX(Total) as FinalTotal ,MAX(Payment) as FinalPayment
FROM si_invoices a 
    left join 
    (select invoice_id, sum(total) as Total from si_invoice_items group by invoice_id) b 
    on a.id = b.invoice_id
    left join
    (select ac_inv_id, sum(payment) as Payment from si_payment group by ac_inv_id) c 
    on c.ac_inv_id = a.id 
group by id
```

or if id is unique:

```
    SELECT *
FROM si_invoices a 
    left join 
    (select invoice_id, sum(total) as Total from si_invoice_items group by invoice_id) b 
    on a.id = b.invoice_id
    left join
    (select ac_inv_id, sum(payment) as Payment from si_payment group by ac_inv_id) c 
    on c.ac_inv_id = a.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your second query worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Details Result:

```
select a.invoice,ac_inv_id,sum(a.total),sum(b.payment) from
(select 1 as id, 100 as invoice, '2014-05-07' as date, 200 as total union all
select  2, 100, '2014-05-07', 200) as a
left join
(select 1 as id, 100 as ac_inv_id, '2014-05-07' as date, 100 as payment union all
select 2, 100, 2014-05-07, 200) as b
on a.id = b.id
```

final query:

```
select a.invoice,ac_inv_id,sum(a.total),sum(b.payment) from
(select * from si_invoice_items) as a
left join
(select * from si_payment) as b
on a.id = b.id
```

result:

```
100 100 400 300
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT `projects`.* , sum( project_tasks.ts_amount ) as cost_spent , sum( work_entries.w_amount ) as actual_amount FROM `projects` LEFT JOIN `project_costs` on `project_costs`.`proj_id` = `projects`.`proj_id` LEFT JOIN `project_tasks` on `project_costs`.`cost_id` = `project_tasks`.`cost_id` LEFT JOIN `work_entries` on `project_costs`.`cost_id` = `work_entries`.`cost_id` and `work_entries`.`w_status` = 'Approved' group by `projects`.`proj_id`;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).